# How to create an identity server for users without consent page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

We have an internal application for internal users which I need to protect using OAuth2/OIDC and thinking of using IdentityServer4. The end users will not be authorizing any applications so there shouldn't be any consent page. I couldn't find any suitable samples, they either are MVC client samples with consent pages or console application clients for Resource Owner Password flows.

Only thing I got is that I need to implement `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` in IDSRV application. That part is I'm OK with. But I couldn't figure out how to setup IDSRV app and MVC app in their Startups.

What do I need to do to protect an .NET Core ASP.NET MVC app with IdentityServer4 using Resource Owner Password flow?

I'd appreciate any help.

**Solution:**

I've ended up using Hybrid flow with manuel user login instead of Resource Owner Password flow. Here's the working solution I've created:

https://github.com/deastr/IdentityServer4.HybridFlow.NoConsent

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the Client definition add the following

```
RequireConsent = false,
```

Comment: I've tried AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword and  RequireConsent = false but instead of redirect I'm just getting unauthorized_client error. Changing grant type to Implicit works but then I get redirected to consent page even with RequireConsent = false..

Comment: Have you tried turning on logging? In my experience with IdentityServer3, enabling logging is the easiest way to solve this sort of _getting started_ problem. You can make Identity Server log a very verbose trace of what is going on - it generally explains these problems for me.

Comment: Yes running IdentityServer4 host as console application displays all kind of logs, which helped alot. I've managed to do what I want using Hybrid flow and RequireConsent=false. Thank you.

Comment: @YahyaHussein I remember having the same reaction as you :-)